# Stripe CLI: testing action when trial period ends

Tags: stripe-payments

I'd like to be able to test locally that the correct actions are taken when the trial period for a user ends.

I set up the Stripe CLI, and start listening:

```
stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:8000/api/stripe-webhook
```

When a trial comes to an end, the `customer.subscription.updated` event will occur.

I trigger this event using the Stripe CLI:

```
stripe trigger customer.subscription.updated
```

On my server side I can see that `payload['data']['previous_attributes']` contains a metadata array with `foo = null`. When a trial ends, we should get `previous_attributes` containing something like: `{ "status": "trialing"...`

I'm wondering if it's possible to trigger an event using the Stripe CLI that mimics a user trial ending (or maybe even just a way to set the `previous_attributes` to similar values that'd occur in a live environment when a trial ends)? If it's possible to do that then it'd be a little easier to test locally that the appropriate action occurs when a trial ends without pushing to a prod-like environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to just use `trial_end` to set a very short trial period either when creating a subscription, or on an existing subscription, and wait a couple of minutes for it to end, at which point it will generate the appropriate events.

```
stripe subscriptions update sub_HpOl9vDMzIEfGf --trial-end=`date -v +5M +%s`
```

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing#trials

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-trial_end